# Difference between the two representation of binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

What is the basic difference between the 2 representation of binary tree??

```
 struct node 
 {
 int data;
 struct node *left;
 struct node *right;
 };



 struct Node {

 char data;

 Node *left;

 Node *right;

 };
```

To be specific whats the difference is being created by the use of struct in the left and right               pointer??

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between the two in C++. If I recall correctly the former (struct node *left) was needed in C but not in C++.

Another difference is that the nodes store different data, first one stores an int and the second stores a char.